# VS Code, how to specify the startup file for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am running a Python app in VS Code and every time I run it I have to open the file where the code starts.
Sometimes the file I am looking at is different and it is annoying to have to always remember to open that page again.
To fix this I tried to change the launch.json file but it does not work;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    // "program": "${file}",
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/lecture1nn.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's not what `launch.json` is for at all, see the link in the comment: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387.

Comment: Thank you for that. So launch.json is for debugging and not relevant to my question. The question I have left is how do I set up my startup file? Can this be done in VS Code for Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have a consistent script to execute at startup, you can define a `sitecustomize` module which the `site` module will always import. That way you can have the code in `sitecustomize` do what you want at start-up as a side-effect. See the [`site` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) for details.